# Mongoengine: A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef, LazyReference, ObjectId or documents

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I am new to python flask. I am creating an API for user registration where a user may have multiple languages. so I am referencing list of languages in my user object.

please get my code here..

```
    class User(Document):    
        name = StringField(required=True)
        email = EmailField(required=True, primary_key=True)
        languages = ListField(ReferenceField(Language), required=True)
        
    
    class Language(Document):
        name =   StringField(required=True, unique=True)
        active = BooleanField(default=True)
```

```
    @app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
    def register_user():
    
        request_payload = request.json
    
        user = User(
                name = request_payload["name"],
                email = request_payload["email"]
            )
        for lang in request_payload["languages"]:
            user.languages.append(Language.objects(name=lang))
    
        user.save()
```

```
**Post request Payload
======================**
{
    "name":"xxxx",
    "email":"xxx@gmail.com",
    "languages":["English","Marathi"]
}

**Error:
========**
ValidationError (User:xxx@gmail.com) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef, LazyReference, ObjectId or documents: ['languages'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Document object returns QuerySet ..it was causing that error. ..for loop changed and it worked

```
 for lang in request_payload["languages"]:
        obj = Languages.objects(name=lang)
        # print("******" + str(obj.count()), file=sys.stdout)
        if obj.count() == 0:
            return error_return("Incorrect Language: "+lang+ " is not present in Languages collection", 400)
        for l1 in obj:
            user.languages.append(l1)
```